# Detecting a new user in sendbird Open channel

Tags: sendbird

I am creating a chat system using sendbird and want to online users in an open chat room on my view. The problem is whenever a new user "joins" an "open channel", sendbird sends me System Message without the user's object.

The only way currently is to call the MemberListQuery to find all online users.

Answer (score 0):

SendBird SDK V3 now triggers "userDidEnter" callback with SendBird user object.

Please take a look at our SDK documentation!

https://docs.sendbird.com/ios
https://docs.sendbird.com/android

Thanks!
Jin